# PHP Ming SWFPrebuiltClip Unknown Tag 74

Tags: php, libming

Simply trying to add a prebuilt clip into a PHP Ming project:

```
$clip = new SWFPrebuiltClip('test.swf');
$m->add($clip);
```

On doing this I am encountering the following error which I cannot seem to find any documentation about:

> Fatal error: SWFPrebuiltClip::__construct(): unknown tag 74 in ... on
>   line 10

Any help with what is causing this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must target Flash Player 7 (or lower) when generating an SWF which is going to be loaded using `SWFPrebuiltClip`. Which is odd, really, as PHP Ming can output up to version 8 according to libming's [documentation](http://www.libming.net/docs/libming/Ming_useSWFVersion.html).

Should note that this only appears to be an issue if there is a text field in the SWF being loaded.